# Golang: закодировать строку, чтобы получить ID

Tags: алгоритм, golang

Есть ли нормальный быстрый алгоритм закодирования строки, чтобы получить восьмизначный ID (используется во frontend, для связки определенных элементов). Можете поделиться?

**Пример**: *tab55925907*, где tab — префикc, а другая часть — ID, полученный на основе строки любой длины и из любых символов (x1y2z3). Допустимо заполнить нулями, если строка меньше 8 символов.

```
// p - prefix; s - string;
func GenerateTargetId(s string, p string) string {
    result := p + s[:8]

    return result
}
```

Comment: Как насчёт hash.crc32 и hash.crc64?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать таблицу ASCII.

```
func makeID(s string)(x string){  
var y int = 1  
for i := 0; i < len(s)-1; i++ {  
    y *= int(s[i])  
}  
x = strconv.Itoa(y)  
x = x[0:8]  
x = "tab" + x  
return  
}
```

Только надо следить за строкой которая передается в функцию

Comment: добавить спереди нулей, если число не достаточно большое

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, думаю, ascii норм.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите алгоритм хеширования : MurMur3. На выходе utint64. Вариант имплементации : https://gowalker.org/github.com/spaolacci/murmur3